# Javascript top.location.replace with and without parent iFrame

Tags: javascript, frame

I am using a frames page, which contains the following Javascript line:

```
top.contentsFrame.location.replace("/main.jsp");
```

I want to run this page both inside an iFrame, as well as independenty.
In an iFrame it doesn't work, because the top attribute now returns the iFrame. So it can't find "contentsFrame" anymore.

What would be the easiest way to fix this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
parent.top.location.replace("/main.jsp");
```

Comment: Not sure if this would fix it, because the top attribute points to a different location when used inside an iFrame, so I guess it wouldn't find "contentsFrame" then.